# Devexpress - changing value in drop down

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I have something relatively simple.  I have a populated drop down list in my Devexpress .net c# application.  What I want to do is  have a method execute each time a value in that drop down list changes.  Specifically compare the new value in the ddl to something else - at the time it changes, not at save time.

within my

Isn't there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean each time a user selects a different value? `SelectedIndexChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a SelectIndexChanged event, like this.

```
private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code here
}
```